# Entity Framework and ObjectMaterialized on dynamic objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an issue with the ObjectMaterialized event in Entity Framework.
This event seems to occur only when serializing objects that are models of the database (a DbSet in the DbContext).
When retrieving a dynamic object, the event is not called.

I have reproduced a simple example of this :

`var posts = db.Posts.Where(x => {{condition}}).ToList();`

-> ObjectMaterialized is triggered

`var posts2 = db.Posts.Where(x => {{condition}}).Select(x => new { content = x.Content, date= x.StartDate }).ToList();`

-> ObjectMaterialized is not triggered

Does someone know about that, and how I can trigger a function on every materialized objects retrieved from Entity Framework, including dynamic objects ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @PaulHiles to be honest I can't remember how I solved this and I don't work for the same compagny anymore.